# clear interval on hover with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, settimeout, setinterval

I've got a carousel with an interval in a `useEffect` hook to trigger automatic slide. I'd like to stop the auto slide as long as I'm hovering the whole section.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        paginate(1)
    }, 3000)
    return () => clearInterval(timer)
})

return (
    <div>
        // the carousel
    </div>
)
```

When I'm trying to get the `timer` function out of the hook, the carousel goes nuts and slides randomly...

It may be a copy of previously asked questions, but I found nothing about react.

How am I supposed to do that right?

Comment: Why don't you define the `timer` as a class variable (outside of `useEffect`), initialize as null, assign in the `useEffect` and clear the interval on hover by referencing that `timer`

Comment: We have readability restrictions on this project, and I can't use ol'reliable class variables here - best I can do is using react hooks, but I don't have any reference on how it would work with timers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that you can do is use `setTimeout` instead, updating a state variable `timer` each `n` ms, and a state variable `hover` that will stop the decrementation of the timer

```
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(3000);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hover) return;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (timer <= 0) {
        setTimer(3000);
        paginate(1);
      } else setTimer(timer - 100)
    }, 100)
  }, [timer, hover])
```

Comment: lovely! excacly what I needed! I just had to change the `hover` state with `onMouseOver` and `onMouseLeave`, then everythin worked like a charm! Thank you!